# Jquery .hide() and .show() not work with IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

This .show and .hide works great in Firefox, Chrome, Safari but not in IE 7. In IE the span doesn't hide, it alway show all of (three) tabs.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
<script>
var currentTab = 0; 

function openTab(clickedTab) {
    var thisTab = $(".tabbed-box .tabs a").index(clickedTab);
    $(".tabbed-box .tabs li a").removeClass("active");
    $(".tabbed-box .tabs li a:eq("+thisTab+")").addClass("active");
    $(".tabbed-box .tabbed-content").hide();
    $(".tabbed-box .tabbed-content:eq("+thisTab+")").show();
    currentTab = thisTab;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs li:eq(0) a").css("border-left", "none");

    $(".tabbed-box .tabs li a").click(function() { 
        openTab($(this)); return false; 
    });

    $(".tabbed-box .tabs li a:eq("+currentTab+")").click();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the running code for example on jsfiddle? Or at least post the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A `span` tag can only contain other inline elements, but I suspect that you have block elements inside your tabs.

If you would dig deeper into what's happening in IE7, I think that you will find that the `span` elements are hidden just fine, but the browser has made an attempt to correct the invalid HTML code so that the contents of the tabs are no longer inside the `span` tags.

If that is the case, just using `div` tags instead of `span` tags for the tabs would solve the problem.